# sdl2_ttf configure error finding free type 2 lib

Tags: macos, sdl-2, freetype, sdl-ttf

I'm trying to install the SDL2_ttf library using the command line but not find how the configure process find the free type 2 previously installed.

```
checking for FreeType -- version >= 7.0.1... no
configure: WARNING:

  The freetype-config script installed by FreeType 2 could not be found.
  If FreeType 2 was installed in PREFIX, make sure PREFIX/bin is in
  your path, or set the FT2_CONFIG environment variable to the
  full path to freetype-config.

configure: error: *** Unable to find FreeType2 library (http://www.freetype.org/)
```

The free type library is installed in the following address :
/usr/local/include/freetype2 --> the headers
/usr/local/lib --> the lib

The process is made on OS X, last version.